# Can Solaris filter SCTP heartbeat messages?

Tags: solaris, sctp

Does Solaris provide a tool for detecting and filtering SCTP Heartbeat chunks? flowadm can detect SCTP traffic but not specific types of SCTP packets. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I would try recent libpcap/tcpdump.